# vim YouCompleteMe. command to return to where you came from?

Tags: vim

After YcmCompleter GoToDefinition.

How to go back where I came from ??

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should go through the `vimtutor` again. One of the first things it talks about is using  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>]</kbd>  to follow a tag, and  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>o</kbd>  to go back.

For what it's worth,  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>i</kbd>  goes forward again. So for example, you might `gg` to the top of a document, hit  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>o</kbd>  (bringing you back to where you started), and then hit  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>i</kbd>  (bringing you back to the top of the document).

Try `h: jump-motions`, or `h: CTRL-O` for more.

Comment: For completeness; note that this doesn't work when one has moved to another file. One then  has to go to the previous buffer. Also, '' (two presses of ') does the same thing and may be ergonomic

Comment: @KanchanKumar For me, `C-o` and `C-i` works when you go to another buffer using `YcmCompleter GoToDefinition`